# Prevent building backend in Heroku when frontend is modified

Tags: heroku

Hello i have a repository with the following structure:

- /backend
- /frontend

I want to allow Heroku builds and deploy only when changes are made in backend subdirectory.

I have configured heroku build pack : https://github.com/timanovsky/subdir-heroku-buildpack.git

Adding the env PROJECT_PATH=backend

Heroku successfully builds the subdirectory "backend" (when pushing my branch) but the problem is that it is also building and deploying when a changes are made in the "frontend" subdirectory.

Comment: To Heroku, that's one application. You can't pick and choose which parts get built. If you want to separate your builds, deploy your front-end separately from your back-end.

Comment: Do you mean to have frontend and backend in two different repositories?

Comment: Yes, two different repositories deployed as two different apps.